# Will conduit fill rules allow 2 4ga bare copper ground wires in a single 1/2 inch liquidtite pvc flexible conduit run?

Tags: electrical, conduit, junction-box

### Background and configuration:

I am providing mechanical protection and neatness for a **4ga grounding electrode conductor** and a 2nd **4ga auxiliary grounding conductor** running from outdoors into (and through) a small weatherproof junction box mounted under my service panel (in exterior-accessible cabinet on garage outside wall).

The box has 3 1/2 inch knockouts, so I would like to use one for an exiting bare ground with intersystem bonding bridge, a 2nd for exit of GEC with Kenny clamp (and Kenny clamp entry to service panel enclosure), leaving the 3rd for entry of both grounding conductors. The GEC will be unbroken but bonded to the auxiliary grounding wire inside the box via a split bolt.

Here's the junction box:

[image]

### Question

Can I run both 4ga grounding conductors into this junction box inside the same 1/2" pvc flexible liquidtite conduit?  I found the following allowed fill table, presumably for current-carrying conductors:

[image]

Comment: Usually it is current heating the wires for fill calculations.  Ground wires should not carry current or heat up, so should not be a factor in the fill.  Assuming no current carrying wires are added in the conduit , just the grounds.

Answer (score 2):

### You're fine on fill

A ½" LFNC-C conduit has 60.4mm2 of usable fill area for 2 wires, and is the worst case for LFNC (LFNC-A and LFNC-B both have slightly more usable fill area), while a 4AWG bare stranded copper wire occupies 21.15mm2 of cross-sectional area, so you still have plenty of room left over after running the 2 4AWG copper wires down the conduit.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment states Grounding conductors are not considered to be current caring conductors, so conduit fill is not a factor in this situation. That being said, if you are planning to use any metal boxes or fittings, they must be bonded to the grounding conductors to prevent then from "choking" current flow in the event of a fault. I would suggest using all plastic, nylon or pvc fitting and boxes.

Happy New Year